# org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found

Tags: spring, jackson, resttemplate

I am hitting a service to find the details of a person, the response is in xml format like the following:

```
<ArrayOfPersonResults xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<PersonResults>
<Name>John Doe</Name>
<State>NY</State>
<Zip>12345</Zip>
</PersonResults>
</ArrayOfPersonResults>
```

I am making use of Spring RestTempate and mapping the response to the following POJOs,

```
public class Person {

    private String zip;

    private String name;

    private String state;


    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }
@JsonProperty("Zip")
    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
@JsonProperty("Name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

@JsonProperty("State")
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

}
```

I invoke the service using rest template,

```
public Person[] getPersosn(String personId) {
        try {
            return getRestTemplate().getForObject(personServiceURL, Person[].class, personId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But I keep getting the exception,
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Lcom.cdk.dataloader.model.Person;] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]

I am not sure why I am getting this, any help appreciated.

Comment: Is your content XML or JSON?

Comment: content is in xml format. I solved this issue by adding the jackson-databind dependency in my pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

Your content type is `application/json;charset=utf-8` but you got XML. Chanage the content to JSON or change content type to be one of `text/xml, application/xml`

Comment: I have set the content type like so,
httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

But I still get the exception,
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class [Lcom.cdk.dataloader.model.State;] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-16]